# How to i get transaction funding source

Tags: paypal

I use api classic and operation TransactionSearch and GetTransactionDetails for searches transaction

```
$transactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType();
$transactionSearchRequest->StartDate = Utils::DateConvert($start_date);
$transactionSearchRequest->EndDate = Utils::DateConvert($start_date + $interval);
$tranSearchReq = new TransactionSearchReq();
$tranSearchReq->TransactionSearchRequest = $transactionSearchRequest;

$paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(Configuration::getAcctAndConfig());

$transactionSearchResponse = $paypalService->TransactionSearch($tranSearchReq);
$paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(Configuration::getAcctAndConfig());
$transactionSearchResponse = $paypalService->TransactionSearch($tranSearchReq);
print_r($transactionSearchResponse);
```

response:

```
[0] => PaymentTransactionSearchResultType Object (
[Timestamp] => 2015-07-09T01:20:10Z
[Timezone] => GMT
[Type] => Payment
[Payer] => xxx@xxx.com
[PayerDisplayName] => Xxx Inc.
[TransactionID] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[Status] => Completed
[GrossAmount] => BasicAmountType Object ([currencyID] => USD, [value] => -129.38)
[FeeAmount] => BasicAmountType Object ([currencyID] => USD, [value] => 0)
[NetAmount] => BasicAmountType Object ([currencyID] => USD, [value] => -129.38)
)
```

But this function (TransactionSearch and GetTransactionDetails(very large array, i will not write a response)) dont have funding source, how to i get transaction funding source?

image http://i60.tinypic.com/30trq0m.png

P.S. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to funding source information for transactions you receive.

That is private to the sender.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i have all the private data, it should be a way to get this information...

Comment: Are you are looking up transaction that you are sending? If so, you can get funding source. If you are looking up transactions that you are receiving, you cannot get that information, whether from API or otherwise.

Comment: if up, what function?